# How do I deal with different XTAL pin capacitance when selecting XTAL and load capacitors

Tags: microcontroller, crystal, capacitance

I'm trying to select a 32kHz crystal and appropriate load capacitors for Atmega48A MCU.

[Atmega48A](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) specifies different capacitances for Xtal1 and Xtal2 pins:

18pF for Xtal1
8pF for Xtal2

The datasheet says: "The capacitance (Ce+Ci) needed at each TOSC pin can be calculated by using:C = 2 * CL – Cs" Where CL is load capacitance specified for the crystal and Cs is stray capacitance.

Can I assume that each pin has (18+8)/2=13pF of capacitance? Can I select a 8pF crystal and use it without external load caps assuming ~3pF of stray capacitance?

Answer (score 2):

The capacitance of the two pins in series is (18*8)/(18+8) = 5.5pF. So with a little stray capacitance (5pF per pin, approx. 2.5pF in series), that should match the 8pF crystal without additional capacitance.

Comment: Seems you know your stuff... could you take a peek at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again to see if you have any comments?