# Crystal oscillator load capacitance voltage rating

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, capacitance, crystal, parasitic-capacitance

I am using [this crystal](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/abracon-llc/ABM3B-8-000MHZ-10-D1G-T/5980052?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIICECyBmBBaAHAOgAz6QAkAtdARl3QBFz0BxdAFRAF0BfIA) oscillator in my design.I know how to calculate the load capacitor.

The XTAL is connected to this [microprocessor](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAMA5D2-Series-Datasheet-ds60001476.pdf).

May I know how to select the voltage rating of the load capacitor

Comment: What component are you using that Xtal with? Microcontroller/microprocessor, oscillator module, ADC/DAC, or something else? Put a link to the datasheet of that component as well.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: There is a big difference between a crystal and a crystal oscillator. When you say you know how to calculate the load capacitor surely you mean you know how to read a data sheet that tells you that value?

Comment: For this crystal the load capacitance is 10pf(From the datasheet).I can use the equations in this question to calculate the value (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the internals of the microprocessor you use but [Pierce Oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator) is quite common in MCUs:

[image]

Image Source: [This publication](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4076398_Top-down_and_bottom-up_approaches_to_stable_clock_synthesis)

Ignore the values shown above as they are just for reference, but the overall structure is pretty much the same. The series RLC network represents the quartz crystal, and the two 30p capacitors are those you place externally taking the load capacitance of the crystal into account.

So I'm assuming a similar structure is in your microprocessor. As can be seen from the schematic above, we can't expect the oscillations to hit VDD level as they start to clip which is an unwanted behaviour. Also, the chip designers tend to keep the amplitudes as low as possible because they affect the power dissipation. Plus, higher amplitudes may cause excess vibrations therefore damage the crystal.

So, for the external capacitors,

- Try to choose MLCC (multi-layer ceramic capacitors) for size and cost.
- Try to choose NP0/C0G instead of X7R/X5R (Although it's not common to see X7R/X5R having pF capacitances) because the oscillations may have a DC offset which has affect on MLCCs i.e. capacitance change with DC offset is minimal on C0G/NP0 compared to X7R/X5R.
- The voltage rating should be higher than maximum VDD of the MCU. Keep the size requirements in mind i.e. don't go for a ridiculously big-size capacitor just to keep some safety margin.

Comment: And be aware that the load capacitance given in the datasheet for the crystal is the capacitance of both of those capacitors in series, not of either capacitor alone. If the datasheet says 20 pF, you should use two 40 pF capacitors. (actually, you should reduce that by a handful of picofarads, to compensate for the parasitic capacitances on the PCB and the input capacitance of the microcontroller. You can do the math, or if this isn't a precision application just fudge the numbers a bit; it'll just change the oscillation frequency slightly.)

Comment: (I know that's not what the question asked, but people get this wrong so often that I think it's worth noting whenever people ask about load capacitors for a Pierce oscillator.)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, when posing a question, please provide more specificity. This will enable others to offer more precise answers.

When selecting the voltage rating of the load capacitor for a crystal oscillator connected to a microprocessor, you'll want to consider the following:

1. **Operating Voltage of the Microprocessor's Oscillator Circuit**: Check the voltage specification of the microprocessor’s oscillator circuit or the power supply voltage of the microprocessor. If, for example, the microprocessor operates at 3.3V, then the oscillator circuit is also likely to operate at this voltage.
2. **Safety Margin**: Always choose a capacitor voltage rating significantly higher than the operating voltage to ensure longevity and reliability. A good rule of thumb is to select a capacitor with a voltage rating at least twice the operating voltage. This margin accounts for possible voltage spikes or fluctuations and ensures the capacitor doesn't break down over time.
3. **Physical Size and Cost**: Higher voltage-rated capacitors might be physically larger and slightly more expensive. However, for common values like 10V, 16V, or 25V, the size and cost differences are often negligible for small ceramic capacitors used as load capacitors.
4. **Quality and Reliability**: While the voltage rating is essential, also consider the quality of the capacitor. For critical applications, you might want to use capacitors from reputable manufacturers and ensure they meet necessary standards.
5. **Temperature and Aging Factors**: Over time and under temperature stress, the effective voltage rating of a capacitor can decrease. The safety margin helps account for this.
6. **Other Factors**: Sometimes, other circuit elements might induce voltages on the crystal pins. Although uncommon, it's good practice to be aware of such scenarios, especially if your design is intricate or there are nearby high-frequency or high-power components.

In summary, if you're using a 3.3V microprocessor, a capacitor with a voltage rating of at least 6.6V (so, practically a 10V or 16V capacitor) should be sufficient. If you're working with a 5V microprocessor, a capacitor rated at 10V might work, but using a 16V one gives a better safety margin. Always check the datasheets of both the microprocessor and the crystal to see if there are any specific recommendations or requirements.